# how to increase jquery :eq() parameter out of hover function?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.arrow').eq(0).hover(function () {
    $('.sub-menu').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.arrow').eq(1).hover(function () {
        $('.sub-menu').eq(1).css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.arrow').eq(2).hover(function () {
            $('.sub-menu').eq(2).css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('.arrow').eq(3).hover(function () {
                $('.sub-menu').eq(3).css('visibility', 'visible');
                $('.arrow').eq(4).hover(function () {
                    $('.sub-menu').eq(4).css('visibility', 'visible');
                    $('.arrow').eq(5).hover(function () {
                        $('.sub-menu').eq(5).css('visibility', 'visible');
                        $('.arrow').eq(6).hover(function () {
                            $('.sub-menu').eq(6).css('visibility', 'visible');
                            $('.arrow').eq(7).hover(function () {
                                $('.sub-menu').eq(7).css('visibility', 'visible');

                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

can I have a function which add class to the children if parent is hovered?
I want to make a navigation to wp themes. thanks))

Comment: Eurgh. You realise you are attaching events on top of events every time you hover your parent-most element?

Comment: meh... Don't use $ everywhere!

Comment: Why even bother adding a class, just use the pseudo-class [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover) in your CSS?

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you're after?

```
$('.parent').hover(function() {
    $(this).children().addClass('className');
});
```

Edit: I don't think you wanted something this generic... I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do there, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
// Listen for hover of ANY .arrow
$('.arrow').hover(
    function(){
        // Hover enter
        // Target a .sub-menu with the same index and show it
        $('.sub-menu').eq($(this).index()).css('visibility', 'visible');
    },
    function(){
        // Hover exit
        // Target a .sub-menu with the same index and hide it
        $('.sub-menu').eq($(this).index()).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
);
```

For the record:

Yes I know this can be optimized to a certain extent but I think this will help OP understand the power and versatility of jQuery a little better.